# ¿Cómo aplicar de manera correcta bootstrap multiselect?

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap, multiselect

Tengo un `multiselect` que hice con unas librerías que tiene bootstrap, pero al momento de aplicarlo y hacer que funcione todo bien, lo que pasa es que no se aplican los diseños correctamente como se ven en los ejemplos en los que me guíe de la pagina de la respectiva librería, que es [ésta](http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/index.html) y no sé sí es como estoy importando las librerías, así que, sí alguien me ayuda, se lo agradezco

`HTML`

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta id="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link REL=StyleSheet HREF="\Jomar\users_control\config\estilos.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Jomar/users_control/images/favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
    <title>Realizar registro</title>
</head>
```

`HTML Select` al que le estoy incluyendo el `multiselect`

```
<label for="empleado" class="col-form-label">Empleado:</label>
                <div class='col-sm-4 mr-3'>
                    <select type="text" size="5" class="" id="empleado" name="empleado" disabled="disabled" multiple>
                        <option value="0" disabled>Seleccionar empleado</option>
                    </select>
                    <div id="mascara" onclick="empleadoIsEmpty()"></div>
                </div>
```

`JQuery`

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
        $('#empleado').multiselect({ 
            buttonWidth: '200px',
            inheritClass: true,
            buttonText: function(options, select) {
                if (options.length === 0) {
                    return 'Seleccionar Empleados';
                }
                if (options.length === select[0].length) {
                    return 'Todos ('+select[0].length+')';
                }
                else if (options.length >= 1) {
                    return options.length + ' Seleccionados';
                }
            }

        });
    });
```

Comment: Según la doc, te falta el archivo require.js

Comment: Cambie el enlace, eso es como para incluir otra cosa más, no estoy seguro, pero no lo estoy usando

Comment: Si no estás seguro, ¿porqué no lo pruebas? Lo agregaste y sigue sin funcionar?

Comment: A ver veo, pero pues, el problema que tengo es más como que no quiere aplicar bien el diseño, voy a revisar igual

Comment: puedes subir tu código completo? para así ayudarte

Comment: @vcasas Ya miro